# Rendered fewer hooks than expected when using a react-redux translate function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I get a `Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.` message when I'm using the following code:

```
{headRows
    // Filter table columns based on user selected input
    .filter(item => displayedColumns.includes(item.id))
    .map(row => (
      <TableCell
        key={row.id}
        align={row.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
        padding={row.disablePadding ? "none" : "default"}
        sortDirection={orderBy === row.id ? order : false}
      >
        <TableSortLabel
          active={orderBy === row.id}
          direction={order}
          onClick={createSortHandler(row.id)}
        >
          {useTranslation(row.label)}
        </TableSortLabel>
      </TableCell>
))}
```

My translate function looks like this:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const useTranslations = () =>
    useSelector(state => state.translations.data, []);
```

If I pass a string into it , the translate function is working as expected. However, if I replace `{useTranslation(row.label)}` with `{row.label}`, I don't receive the error message anymore. In my opinion I don't call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions here, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a component which renders a list of cells. But each cell here rendered by a callback passed to the `map`. So, in fact, you have both a loop and nested function here.

I would suggest you extract the callback to a new component and render it. In that case, every cell will be a new component which allows you to use hooks freely.

```
const MyTableCell = props => {
   const {row} = props;
   const title = useTranslation(row.label);
   return (
       <TableCell>
        <TableSortLabel>
          {title}
        </TableSortLabel>
      </TableCell>
   )

}

// and then

{headRows
    // Filter table columns based on user selected input
    .filter(item => displayedColumns.includes(item.id))
    .map(row => (
      <MyTableCell row={row} key={row.id} />
))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I was able to see what was going wrong. I also found an offical [ESLint plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) which helps in the future to prevent errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

-- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this count as a nested function or what exactly is here the problem? How can I then achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: You're calling it in a loop (of which the length likely changes).